# Resizing image or cell to make the picture as i want

Tags: excel, vba

I already have code written in VBA, it's all working, but I need to resize the picture to make it a little bit bigger.

What I need to do in the below to resize it?

```
Sub InsertPictures()
'Update 20140513
Dim Picture() As Variant
Dim PicFormat As String
Dim Picturee As Object
Dim Rng As Range

Dim sShape As Shape


On Error Resume Next
PicList = Application.GetOpenFilename(PicFormat, MultiSelect:=True)
xColIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Column
If IsArray(PicList) Then
    xRowIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Row
    For lLoop = LBound(PicList) To UBound(PicList)

        Set Rng = Cells(xRowIndex, xColIndex)
        Set sShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(PicList(lLoop), msoFalse, msoCTrue, Rng.Left, Rng.Top, Rng.Width, Rng.Height)
        xRowIndex = xRowIndex + 4

    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

u can define any size you want. just use Width and Height.

This will add 100 px to the size of the image

```
For lLoop = LBound(PicList) To UBound(PicList)

    Set Rng = Cells(xRowIndex, xColIndex)
    Set sShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(PicList(lLoop), msoFalse, msoCTrue, Rng.Left, Rng.Top, Rng.Width, Rng.Height)

    sShape.Width = sShape.Width + 100
    sShape.Height = sShape.Height + 100

    xRowIndex = xRowIndex + 4

Next
```

or simply

```
    Set sShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(PicList(lLoop), msoFalse, msoCTrue, Rng.Left, Rng.Top, Rng.Width+100, Rng.Height+100)
```